# remove intersection of two sets A and B from set A in redis

Tags: redis

I have two sets in Redis - ProcessedUrls and PendingUrls.
I want to do in one redis query the following:
Remove all the keys that are in both pending and processed sets from the Pendings set and after that return 100(or any other number - X) values of the Pending set.

Should I do it via Lua(redis server-side scripting language)?
I would think there's a more simple way.

Thansk for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SDIFFSTORE` command to get the diff items and save it back to the pending set:

```
SDIFFSTORE PendingUrls PendingUrls ProcessedUrls
```

Then you can use `SRANDMEMBER PendingUrls N` command to randomly get `N` members in the pending set.

If you want to make these two operations atomic, wrap them into a Lua script or transaction.